# Can't build iOS App with Flutter Firestore on Xcode 13 on a M1

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods, apple-m1

I use a Mac M1 and I upgrade to Xcode13. When I try to build my code I have this long error list. Those errors come just after upgrading to Xcode 13.

```
Xcode's output:
```

↳
/Users/seb/Developer/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
url_launcher-6.0.12/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:140:57: warning:
'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used
for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window
across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
.keyWindow.rootViewCo
ntroller];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/url_launcher/url_launcher-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow
API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple
scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0,
13.0));
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
url_launcher-6.0.12/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:140:57: warning:
'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used
for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window
across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
.keyWindow.rootViewCo
ntroller];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/url_launcher/url_launcher-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow
API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple
scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0,
13.0));
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
geolocator_apple-1.2.2/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:157:21: warning:
'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
geolocator_apple-1.2.2/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:157:21: warning:
'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
openURL:requestURL];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:
completionHandle
r:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
2 warnings generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:52:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:131:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:132:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
^~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:168:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
openURL:requestURL];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:com
pletionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:191:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
5 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:52:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:131:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:132:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
^~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:168:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
openURL:requestURL];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:com
pletionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:191:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS
/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariSer
vices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note:
'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
^
5 warnings generated.
error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further
output
CompileC
/Users/seb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-chsunpzbxomjegfdzqfzlx
lqocdc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMAppAu
th.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization+Keychain.o
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth/Sour
ces/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization+Keychain.m normal x86_64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from
project 'Pods')
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth/Sour
ces/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization+Keychain.m:31:26: warning:
'unarchiveObjectWithData:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - Use
+unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:passwordData];
^
In module 'Foundation' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth/Sour
ces/Public/GTMAppAuth/GTMKeychain.h:19:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
n.framework/Headers/NSKeyedArchiver.h:152:1: note:
'unarchiveObjectWithData:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
+ (nullable id)unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)data API_DEPRECATED("Use
+unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead", macosx(10.2,10.14),
ios(2.0,12.0), watchos(2.0,5.0), tvos(9.0,12.0));
^
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth/Sour
ces/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization+Keychain.m:41:48: warning:
'archivedDataWithRootObject:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 -
Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
NSData *authorizationData = [NSKeyedArchiver
archivedDataWithRootObject:auth];
^
In module 'Foundation' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth/Sour
ces/Public/GTMAppAuth/GTMKeychain.h:19:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundatio
n.framework/Headers/NSKeyedArchiver.h:47:1: note:
'archivedDataWithRootObject:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
+ (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject API_DEPRECATED("Use
+archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead",
macosx(10.2,10.14), ios(2.0,12.0), watchos(2.0,5.0), tvos(9.0,12.0));
^
2 warnings generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
google_sign_in-4.5.9/ios/Classes/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.m:250:57: warning:
'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used
for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window
across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
.keyWindow.rootViewCo
ntroller];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/google_sign_in/google_sign_in-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow
API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple
scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0,
13.0));
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/seb/Developer/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
google_sign_in-4.5.9/ios/Classes/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.m:250:57: warning:
'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used
for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window
across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
.keyWindow.rootViewCo
ntroller];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/google_sign_in/google_sign_in-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platfor
m/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.fra
mework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow
API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple
scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0,
13.0));
^
1 warning generated.
ld: in
/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/Go
ogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDEMMErrorHandler_3a47e13d8ca81b41e9cdb7e
f5468004a.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built
for iOS, file
'/Users/seb/Developer/conduiteaccompagnee/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/G
oogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

Try clean up the pod cache and re-install with the following

```
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
pod install 
flutter run
```

if this does not resolve the issue then Here are the steps :

Created a new flutter project

Copied the android & lib folders (since they weren't causing any issues) and also the pubspec.yml and .lock files.

Then, I copied the firebase-related files into the ios directory along with the SwiftDelegate since I made some changes in order to support google maps.
Once that was done, all I had to do was run pod install and when inevitably the pod dependency version issue arose, I simply run pod update and that fixed any issues I had with the pods.

Final step was to exclude the arm64 architecture from BOTH the Runner target and the Pods target and change the minimum ios version to 9.

That's it, once those things were done everything worked just fine.